# Why do we use a low resistors on Data lines for an ADC for example or a clock?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, clock, data

Why do we use a low resistors on Data lines for an ADC for example or a clock ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The resistor R3 is used for many things that are all related:

- impedance matching
- source termination
- slew rate limiting
- bandwidth limiting
- reducing electromagnetic interference
- preventing crosstalk
- preventing ringing
- preventing reflections

Comment: Aren't impedance matching, source termination, preventing ringing, and preventing reflections all essentially the same reason?

Comment: could explain more ?

Comment: Not quite DKN but there is certainly a lot of Tautology or redundant descriptors.  The real reason is 3.6V logic is near 25 ohms at 3.3.V so adding 22 makes it close to 50 Ohms which reduces the ringing for controlled impedance tracks near this value.

Comment: Did you understand my correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

The resistor, together with the driver source impedance, provides a matched termination for the driven line. It absorbs reflections from the far end of the trace.

The signal will look terrible at the resistor, but clean at the trace destination.